# What is odd-even register pairing in Sparc processor?

Tags: sparc

A Sparc simulator that I have gave me `Trap: illegal_instruction, Destination is an odd-even register pair` for an `ld` instruction.

What exactly is the odd-even pairing in the processor? Does it have something to do with memory alignment? I have gone through the manual but it wasn't explained in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not absolutely sure, but the error message might refer to an `ldd` instruction:

The `ldd` instruction loads two registers at once: The even register (e.g. `i2`) specified and the following odd register (e.g. `i3`).

According to the Sparc v8 manual, there may be two different behaviors if you specify an odd register (such as `i3`) depending on the actual CPU used:

- Some CPUs will cause an exception (this is what seems to happen in your case)
- Other CPUs ignore the low bit of the register number and interpret `i3` as `i2` (because `i3` would be loaded anyway, this also makes sense)